# Undefined Symbols when compiling MinilibX on macOS

Tags: c, gcc, x11

I am trying to compile [this library](https://github.com/42Paris/minilibx-linux) (MinilibX) with a simple 'Hello world' type application, but I get the following error:

```
$ make -C mlx
$ gcc main.c -I. -Lmlx -lmlx ./mlx/libmlx_Darwin.a -framework OpenGL -framework Appkit

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_XChangeWindowAttributes", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_set_win_event_mask in libmlx.a(mlx_int_set_win_event_mask.o)
  "_XCreateColormap", referenced from:
      _mlx_init in libmlx.a(mlx_init.o)
  "_XCreateGC", referenced from:
      _mlx_new_window in libmlx.a(mlx_new_window.o)
  "_XCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _mlx_new_window in libmlx.a(mlx_new_window.o)
  "_XGetVisualInfo", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_get_visual in libmlx.a(mlx_int_get_visual.o)
  "_XGetWMNormalHints", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_anti_resize_win in libmlx.a(mlx_int_anti_resize_win.o)
  "_XInternAtom", referenced from:
      _mlx_init in libmlx.a(mlx_init.o)
  "_XMapRaised", referenced from:
      _mlx_new_window in libmlx.a(mlx_new_window.o)
  "_XNextEvent", referenced from:
      _mlx_loop in libmlx.a(mlx_loop.o)
  "_XOpenDisplay", referenced from:
      _mlx_init in libmlx.a(mlx_init.o)
  "_XPending", referenced from:
      _mlx_loop in libmlx.a(mlx_loop.o)
  "_XPutBackEvent", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_wait_first_expose in libmlx.a(mlx_int_wait_first_expose.o)
  "_XSetWMNormalHints", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_anti_resize_win in libmlx.a(mlx_int_anti_resize_win.o)
  "_XSetWMProtocols", referenced from:
      _mlx_new_window in libmlx.a(mlx_new_window.o)
  "_XShmPixmapFormat", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_deal_shm in libmlx.a(mlx_init.o)
  "_XShmQueryVersion", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_deal_shm in libmlx.a(mlx_init.o)
  "_XStoreName", referenced from:
      _mlx_new_window in libmlx.a(mlx_new_window.o)
  "_XSync", referenced from:
      _mlx_loop in libmlx.a(mlx_loop.o)
  "_XWindowEvent", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_wait_first_expose in libmlx.a(mlx_int_wait_first_expose.o)
  "_XkbKeycodeToKeysym", referenced from:
      _mlx_int_param_KeyPress in libmlx.a(mlx_int_param_event.o)
      _mlx_int_param_KeyRelease in libmlx.a(mlx_int_param_event.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

GCC:

```
$ gcc -v
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I don't know if I'm linking it wrong, or if there is a conflict between versions/compilers (minilibx uses GCC from what I can tell)...

Here is a minimal reproduction: https://github.com/herbievine/42/tree/so_long/so_long

To run:

```
git clone https://github.com/herbievine/42.git -b so_long
cd 42/so_long
git clone https://github.com/42Paris/minilibx-linux.git mlx
make
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to link with X11 libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @n.m. suggested, linking my code with X11 solved the issue.

My Makefile looks like this:

```
MLX_DIR = ./mlx
MLX_LIB = $(MLX_DIR)/libmlx_$(UNAME).a
MLX_FLAGS = -Lmlx -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit

# added this line
X11_FLAGS = -L/usr/X11/lib -lXext -lX11

SRCS = \
    main.c \

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(MLX_LIB) $(NAME)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Imlx -c -o $@ $<

$(NAME): $(OBJS)                 # link here 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(MLX_FLAGS) $(X11_FLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

$(MLX_LIB):
    @make -C $(MLX_DIR)
```